# How to get access to the store created in the extjs controller?

Tags: extjs

I study examples on ExtJs 6 and try to repeat. Here is an example of changing the remote storage to the local one https://habr.com/en/en/post/138054/ and trying to repeat.
The difficulty was caused by these code fragments.

```js
UsersApp.Utils.ping({
    success: this._onPingSuccess, // Internet is
    failure: this._onPingFailure     // No Internet
  }, this);
```

where

```js
_onPingSuccess: function(){
        // сеть есть
        var win           = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#usersWindow')[0];
        var storeLocal    = this.getStore('storeLocal');
        var store         = this.getStore('store');
        var grid          = win.getComponent('NamesGrid');
```

UsersApp.Utils.ping is a wrapper over Ext.Ajax.request, but the author does not disclose the code. When _onPingSuccess or _onPingFailure is executed, this refers to the Window object that does not have a getStore method.

Full controller code

```js
Ext.define("Apple.controller.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
      'Apple.utils.Ping',
      'Apple.store.OrderStore',
      'Apple.store.UserStore'
    ],

    init: function(){

      Ext.define("Session", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Session",
      });

      var session = Ext.create("Session");

      var store = Ext.create("Apple.store.OrderStore", {
        storeId: 'OrderStore',
        session: session
      });

      store.setProxy(
        Ext.create('Ext.data.RestProxy', {
          type: 'rest',
          url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/order',
          api: {
            create:  'https://localhost:5001/api/order',
            read:    'https://localhost:5001/api/order',
            update:  'https://localhost:5001/api/order',
            destroy: 'https://localhost:5001/api/order'
          },
          writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields : false, //just send changed fields
            allowSingle : true      //always wrap in an array
          },
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
          }
        })
      );

      var local = Ext.create("Apple.store.OrderStore", {
        storeId: 'OrderStoreLocal',
        session: session
      });

      local.setProxy(
        Ext.create('Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage', {
          type: 'localstorage',
          id  : 'Orders'
        })
      );

      local.addListener('load', function(){
        Apple.utils.Ping.sendPing({
          success: this._onPingSuccess, 
          failure: this._onPingFailure
        }, this);
      }, this);

      // initiate loading in local storage
      local.load();
    },

    _onPingSuccess: function(response, options){

      var store = this.getStore('OrderStore');
      var local = this.getStore('OrderStoreLocal');

      var grid  = Ext.getCmp('LayC0Grid');

      // find out the number of records in the local storage
      localCnt = local.getCount();

      // check the status of the local storage,
      // figure out if synchronization is needed
      if (localCnt > 0){
         // synchronization is needed, add entries
         // one by one from local storage
         // to server
        for (i = 0; i < localCnt; i++){
          var localRecord = local.getAt(i);
          var deletedId   = localRecord.data.id;
          delete localRecord.data.id;
          store.add(localRecord.data);
          localRecord.data.id = deletedId;
        }
        // save server storage
        store.sync();
        // we clear local storage
        for (i = 0; i < localCnt; i++){
          local.removeAt(0);
        }
      }

      store.load();
      // we connect server storage to the table
      grid.reconfigure(store);
      grid.store.autoSync = true;
    },
    _onPingFailure: function(response, options){
      var local = this.getStore('OrderStoreLocal');
      var store = this.getStore('OrderStore');

      var grid  = Ext.getCmp('LayC0Grid');

      // set table storage to local
      grid.reconfigure(storeLocal);
      grid.store.autoSync = true;
    }
  });
```

How do I get storage in _onPingSuccess and _onPingFailure without passing them explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the wrapper has been written properly (read as: following ExtJS' typical usage patterns), you can set the `scope` property when calling the `sendPing` method, as follows:

```
      local.addListener('load', function(){
        Apple.utils.Ping.sendPing({
          success: this._onPingSuccess, 
          failure: this._onPingFailure,
          scope: this
        }, this);
      }, this);
```

If, on the other hand, the wrapper wasn't written properly you can then resort to the `bind` method, as follows:

```
      local.addListener('load', function(){
        Apple.utils.Ping.sendPing({
          success: this._onPingSuccess.bind(this), 
          failure: this._onPingFailure.bind(this)
        }, this);
      }, this);
```

At this point the function will run in the scope of the controller, so you should be able to retrieve your store easily.

Comment: unbelievable! it works!
But now the error in the grid.reconfigure (store) [W] XTemplate evaluation exception: Cannot read property 'getById' of undefined. How to track such an error? data is uploaded to the repository but not displayed in the grid

Comment: That error happens, from my experience, in various circumstances difficult to track. The whole code would be necessary to try and sort it out. My advice is to build a minimalistic example doing what you need and then use it as a baseline.

Comment: Anyway, broadly speaking, what ExtJS is trying to do is to retrieve a record based on its ID in order to restore some internal state (selection? scrolling?).
As the ID of the record in the new store is different, ExtJS can't resolve its value and it returns the error.
One thing you can check is whether both stores use the same property as ```idProperty```, but I'm not sure it will work.